# Remove the auto #/ appended to URLs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

I am new to vue js. I have created a project using vue cli 3.

The URLs generated contain #/ at the end, example http://localhost:8080/vuejs#/
I want to get rid of trailing #/, I have tried `mode: "history"` in router.js file as well as added .htaccess file in root directory with following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

but it returns a blank page without any error.

Can anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

with

```
FallbackResource /index.html
```

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Comment: I added FallbackResource /index.html, but still get a blank page